# Kafka local state store of multiple partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am using kafka processor api and I create a state store from a topic of 3 partitions(I have 3 brokers), I have 1 instance of stream. I wonder to know when I get local state store, can I get all keys? Why certain keys work but certain don't? Is it normal?
Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you're talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of application instances does not matter for this case. Because the input topic has 3 partitions, the state store is created with 3 shards. Processing happens with 3 parallel tasks. Each task instantiates a copy of your topology, processes one input topic partition, and uses one shard.

Compare: https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/architecture

If you want to access different shards, you can use "Interactive Queries" feature for key/value lookups (and key-range queried) over all shards.

Also, the is the notion of a global state store, that would load data from all partitions into a single store (not sharding). However, it provided different semantics compared to "regular" stores, because store updates are not time-synchronized with the other processing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, So I can't get all state store contents of 3 shards, then how can I get all of them?

Comment: And one more question, if I understand well, the number of kafka stream instance doesn't mean the same thing as the number of machines, is there a way to detect the number of kafka stream instance?

Comment: Edited my answer. For "Kafka Streams" instances, it means the number of client objects you create (ie, `new KafkaStreams()` that belong to the same `application.id`). Note, that also the number of threads per instance is important. You cannot have more threads than input topic partitions (sum of all threads over all instances), because one topic-partition can only  be processed by a single thread. All other threads would be idle and not process any data.

Comment: Thank you, it's clear for kafka instance. But in my case, as the input topic has multiple partitions, there are several state store shards( there is only one machine and one kafka instance),  I found when I use local state store to get keys, some keys work but others not. So  how can I get all contents of these local state stores?

Comment: Hi @jianma . As explained by Matthias, you may use "Interactive Queries" to get the values in the "other" state stores. You can have more general info about the Interactive Queries at https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html and more specifically,  how to implement and query : https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html#querying-remote-state-stores-for-the-entire-app

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Multiple partitions were assigned to the same app instance that has local store. From your response it's clear that each partition has associated state store shard. Note that different shards could have the same key. From what shard we'll get value if DSL processor makes get call to state store?

Comment: Well, you will have one processor instance per shard, and each processor instance accesses its own shard.